# Font identification of this curvy serif

Tags: fonts, font-identification

does anyone know what typeface/font this is? I have tried whatthefont and whatfontis but no luck.

[image: letters e and a]

Comment: Hi. Where did you find this?  It looks a bit similar to Kaftan Serif, but isn't identical.

Comment: It's used for a brand called Tealise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it:

[Tangerine Regular ttf (400)](https://creativemarket.com/NewTropical/4890580-Tangerine-Retro-Font?u=whatfontis)

Comment: You're my hero!